# property within an interface of same name C#

Tags: c#, interface

```
public interface IBox
{
    IBox id { get; }
}
```

I am trying to understand the intention of `IBox id` here when the interface is implemented on a class.

Why is `IBox id` used here? From my understanding of interface, it lists the design requirement for the class. However, `IBox id` is within `IBox` itself. What are the possible uses of a class created with `IBox` interface implemented?

I tried to create a class with the `IBox` interface.

```
public class Box : IBox
{
    public IBox id { get;}
}
```

What can be achieved by doing this?

Comment: Forces Box to have an Id property. There might be a number of reasons. Perhaps Box is going to be populated from a db and needs to have a populated ID, so it can be persisted back correctly...

Comment: You could have more than one implementation of IBox. Maybe you have an OutterBox implementation and an InnerBox implementation with the InnerBox id = OuterBox.

Comment: Are you asking why an instance of the interface has a property of the same type? So a `Box` has a `Box`? Well, if this is a geometric box, every box itself surely has some bounding-box as well.

Comment: I'd imagine it *could* be alone the same lines as how you'd implement something like a `LinkedList` (i.e. a Node contains a reference to another Node). In your case, an `IBox` had a reference to another `IBox`. As for *why*, we can't really do anything with the given info other than speculate.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, that is what I am trying to mean. Because from my understanding, fields and methods are included in interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what came to my mind first. Not sure if this answers your question though but let's say you are implementing a Linked list data structure. You will probably have some kind of a Node to represent the values in the list:

```
class LinkedList<INode>
{
    public INode Head { get; set; }
}

interface INode
{
    INode Next { get; set; }
}

class Node : INode
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public INode Next { get; set; }
}
```

The interface implementation can be used to ensure that the class will have a reference to itself in order to represent the next element in the linked list.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of use-cases where a type may have a property of itself. Imagine a `Person`. Every instance of that class may have `Children`, which themeselves `Person`s as well and may have other `Children`.

```
class Person
{
    public Person Child;
}
```

In your case one may argue that a box may live within another box or may contain other boxes.

Or let´s think of a `Box` as a surrounding rectangle around some geometric figure. Of course that bounding-box is a geometry in itself, so it may have a bounding-box also (which however will be pretty much the same).